# How can I make kubernetes pods making the host and pods in the same LAN

Tags: kubernetes

If I run the container by myself, I can bridge the docker container to a physical interface using pipework.
But if I use kubernetes + docker, how can I bridge container to physical interface, making the host and pods in the same LAN?

Comment: Can you say more about what you are trying to do? If you are just trying to access your container through a host IP address, you should look into hostPort.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are trying to expose your pod on an IP separate from your host, but in the same network (e.g. not port-mapped/NATed). This is exactly why kubernetes chose its [network model](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/design/networking.md#model-and-motivation). Using [advanced routes](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking#routing) in GCE (or [Flannel](https://github.com/coreos/flannel#flannel), [Weave](https://github.com/weaveworks/weave), [Calico](https://github.com/projectcalico/calico), etc.), Pods all get their own IPs that are accessible to other Pods, and to other Hosts, without NATing.